# Django: 'weblearn' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

I am a beginner with Django, and I have been following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/) tutorial so far - with the small exception of naming the app `weblearn` instead of `polls` as done in the tutorial. So far it worked fine, all worked as expected.

I am in about the half on the fourth page, and just created the file `weblearn/templates/weblearn/results.html`, and I double checked that the name `polls` is not used in any of the code/html.

But still, when I navigate to the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/weblearn/1/` as suggested, I get an error

```
In template /Users/alex/Coding/Django/learnit/weblearn/templates/weblearn/detail.html, error at line 5
'weblearn' is not a registered namespace
```

What can I do to debug this error? I have not the slightest idea what the error could mean...

`detail.html`:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'weblearn:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Comment: Could you please share your `urls.py` content? It could be something like this to allow you to get the url from `weblearn` namespace, path('', include('weblearn.urls', namespace='weblearn'))

Comment: see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `app_name` to you urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'weblearn'

# your urlpatterns
```

This way `{% url 'weblearn:vote' question.id %}` will know it has to look into `weblearn/urls.py`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Did I miss that from the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, it's right [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/#amend-urlconf), above `urlpatterns`. It happened to me a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're using namespace to generate action url, `{% url 'weblearn:vote' question.id %}`, `weblearn` is namespace, `vote` is url name. To make it work, you should define your namespace in ROOT_URLCONF (in settings.py), like so:

project/settings.py (ROOT_URLCONF)

```
from django.urls import include

app_name = 'weblearn'
urlpatterns = [
    path('weblearn/', include('weblearn.urls', namespace='weblearn')),
]
```